# Preventing worklight adapter access from other module

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I have an worklight application which as two modules i.e; user module and admin module. How should I secure my adapters for respective module from not being accessed by other module.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a single application with two separate logics in it - user and admin.

In an application you must specify the adapter name and procedure name of the adapter in order to call it.

So simply put, only call your adapter (and its procedure) in the right module (user or admin) - this is purely applicative as I see it. Don't call an adapter where it shouldn't be called, and it won't.

If this does not answer your question, please further explain the scenario.